# Using spring boot to send email using gmail smtp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to send email using spring boot. I have 3 file as follows

**MailSender.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MailSender
{
    @Autowired
    private static JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        sendemail();
    }
    public static void sendemail() {
        MimeMessage mail = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);
            helper.setTo("emailsendertester24@gmail.com");
            //helper.setReplyTo("someone@localhost");
            helper.setFrom("emailsendertester24@gmail.com");
            helper.setSubject("Lorem ipsum");
            helper.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [...]");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {}
        mailSender.send(mail);
        //return helper;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SendingEmail</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

and **application.properties**

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=*****
spring.mail.password=*****
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 25
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
```

So now when I try to run my MailSender class it gives me an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" on line **MimeMessage mail = mailSender.createMimeMessage();**
I got to know mailSender properties are null as it is not able to get the properties from application.properties file.

Comment: Try starting your application with `--debug` as an argument. It will output an auto-configuration report that will show why there's no `MailSender`

Answer (score 4):

You can maybe go for a solution provided out-of-the-box in the [Spring-Boot-Email-Tools](https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools) project.

It provides also useful features like scheduling, support for template engine and persistence with REDIS.

If you need to send plain text emails you just need to import the core module

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Annotate the main as follows:

```
package com.myapplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEmailTools
public class MainApplication  {

    public static void main(final String... args) {

    }
}
```

provide configurations in the `application.yml` (o `properties`) and autowire the `EmailService` in your component class, e.g.

```
@Autowired
public EmailService emailService;

public void sendEmailWithoutTemplating(){
   final Email email = EmailImpl.builder()
        .from(new InternetAddress("cicero@mala-tempora.currunt", "Marco Tullio Cicerone "))
        .to(Lists.newArrayList(new InternetAddress("titus@de-rerum.natura", "Pomponius Attĭcus")))
        .subject("Laelius de amicitia")
        .body("Firmamentum autem stabilitatis constantiaeque eius, quam in amicitia quaerimus, fides est.")
        .encoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).build();

   emailService.send(email);
}
```

More examples can be found on the GitHub repository of the project. Plus, there is [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sending-scheduling-mime-emails-java-using-spring-boot-roberto-trunfio) on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 2):

This issue appears cause you are using not properly terminated recursion in this block:

```
public static void send() {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setFrom("abc@gmail.com");
    message.setTo("xyz@gmail.com");
    message.setSubject("hello");
    mailSender.send();
}
```

You call mailSender.send() method which is referenced to himself. Change your call inside method.

Comment: Sorry that was a very silly mistake. But now i edited the question. Can you take a look?

Comment: So, if you want to test email sending, you should up your application context which will read your properties("if config is properly configured"). In yours variant context is not initialized, so simplest way is to read properties directly from application.properties and store them into mailing service.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyMailSender {

@Bean
public SenderService senderService() {
    return new SenderService();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyMailSender.class, args);
}
}

public class SenderService {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@PostConstruct
public void send() {
    MimeMessage mail = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);
        helper.setTo("emailsendertester24@gmail.com");
        //helper.setReplyTo("someone@localhost");
        helper.setFrom("emailsendertester24@gmail.com");
        helper.setSubject("Lorem ipsum");
        helper.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [...]");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {}
    mailSender.send(mail);
    //return helper;
}

}
```